# Select entry from array given another value

Tags: python, text, text-files, extract

I have a text file with the format (date, time, resistance):

```
12/11/2013  13:20:38    28.321930E+3
...         ...             ...
```

I need to extract the value of resistance (third column) from every 6 seconds after the first data entry. To start I wanted to import the text file using:

```
date, time, resistance = loadtxt('Thermometers.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0,1,2])
```

However before I've hardly begun my program, I get the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 12/11/2013

**-ALSO-**

I am not sure how to also iterate through time given that the date changes as it's an over-night data run. Elegant solutions to my problem(s) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a problem in opening a text file object and doing readline and finally doing the_line.split()?

Comment: I need to extract data from a time interval, which also requires considering the date.

Comment: Show the definition of the `loadTxt` function, please.

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt(fname, dtype=<type 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0)`
Load data from a text file.

Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.

Comment: Are the data taken at constant time intervals? Further, I think @Jack_of_All_Trades is on the right track - why not just read and split the line using standard Python read/string operations, instead of through numpy?

Comment: Check my answer below using splits and datetime objects.

Comment: Yes, data is taken at constant intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will do what you want to do. And also, you don't have to worry about the overnight data and changing date since this converts it to datetime object.

```
    import datetime

    filtered_data=[]

    my_data=open(my_file,'r')
    for line in my_data:

        data_arr=line.split()
        dte=data_arr[0].split("/") r
        tme=data_arr[1].split(":") 
        new_date=datetime.datetime((int(dte[2]),int(dte[0]),int(dte[1]),
                                    int(tme[0]),int(tme[1]),int(tme[2]))

        if filtered_data==[]:
           filtered_data.append(data_arr)

        else:
           if (new_date-old_date).seconds==6:
                filtered_data.append(data_arr)

        old_date=new_date
```

This will give you a list where the items are filtered as per your situation ( in every 6 seconds). Now if you just want the array of your resistance which are distributed at 6 seconds interval, using simple loop or list comprehension like below will suffice:

```
R_in_six_sec_interval=[R[2] for R in filtered_data]
```

Comment: hmm how about `new_date=dateutil.parser.parse(' '.join(data_arr[:2]),dayfirst=True)` parse the date?

Comment: A few ideas... I think you need to convert the `dte` values to numbers to keep `datetime` happy. Also, wouldn't a conditional of `>= 6` be more appropriate? Another idea is to split the line just once using `re.compile(r'[/:\s]+')`. If you initialize `old_date` to a really old value, you can drop the check for empty `filtered_data`.

Comment: @FMc: You are absolutely right. I remembered at first but forgot it later since it is since int(...). I just commented in my answer. I am being lazy now. I think OP gets the idea now.

Comment: @FMc: For >= 6, I think the OP wants exactly 6 seconds interval from the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a [look at this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) if you want to do stick to numpy for other reasons.